# I can't use OpenDNS in my UBUNTU desktop

Tags: 12.04, opendns

I wanted to use Open DNS solution in my UBUNTU PC. Also I followed the instruction from https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/ubuntu but it's still saying I am not using Open DNS that means configuration was wrong. But I can't understand what's wrong.

My UBUNTU version: `UBUNTU 12.04 LTS`

Output of `sudo /etc/resolv.conf`
+ Output of `sudo vim /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` + output of `sudo ifconfig` can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5557006/

It would be great if anyone can see my problem and suggest me to do right things.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it:

First, open up the network applet menu, and *all* the way at the bottom, select "Edit Connections", like below:

[image]

Now, switch to the wireless (or wired, as the case may be) tab, and select your network connection from the list, and then click the "Edit" button.

[image]

Now, switch to the IPv4 tab.

[image]

Use the second item on the "Method" menu - change it to DHCP Addresses only.

[image]

Then, first enter in the DNS servers: `208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220`, and then click "Save".

[image]

Now, you should be using OpenDNS. If for some reason it doesn't work, go ahead and restart your computer - the changes should *then* take affect.